# Run different functions depending on phone language

Tags: android

I have support for 3 languages in my app. And depending on what language the phone is set to use I want my app to run a function based on that.

Comment: It is hard to answer this as you do not really give enough information about what you want to do or why. Generally best not to use different code for different languages, just use different resources. However if you need to it may be best to consider using application variants to produce different versions of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally best practice is not to use different code for different languages, just use different resources. However if you still need it you can use the Locale class.
If you want to get the selected language of your device:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

If you're interested in just getting the ISO code (e.g. for if or switch statements) use:

```
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can determine this by looking for the devices Locale using the following syntax:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want change the App language use the file strings for each language supported