# Run function depending on selected phone language

Tags: android, function, locale

Is it possible to run a function depending on selected phone language?

I have 3 supported languages. So I have 3 different functions that I want to run.

Thanks

Comment: What are the differences between the languages regarding your functions ?

Comment: why not something like `genericFunction(){ if (english) englishFunction()}`

Comment: Weird how less than a hour apart there was a question nearly exactly the same... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587764/run-different-functions-depending-on-phone-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do that.

First, get the system language using the following snippet:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

You'll get a `String` as a result, something like "en", "ru", "pt". And then you can use an `if` statement to call your functions accordingly, or like it was suggested on the comments, you can create a generic function and call that snippet inside of it.

Something like:

```
void myFunction() {
    String myLocale = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

    if (myLocale.equals("en")) {
        // do something.
    }
    else if (myLocale.equals("ru")) {
        // do something else.
    }
}
```

For more info on `Locale`, please refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

Comment: Thanks alot really helpful